# Dynamic ARM templates parameter value

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am currently using the ARM templates to deploy an Azure function app. I have something like this.

```
  "$schema": ...
  "contentVersion": ...
 "parameters":{
    "appSetting":{
      "value":{
          "testSetting" : "testvalue1"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the testSetting parameter value to be random by appending either the dateTime of when I run the deployment script(e.g. testvalue3060) or increment the value by changing it to testValue2, testValue3, etc.

I looked into the this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-date and it seems it is not feasible except if you do that when you are declaring it inside the default value assign. Is there any other way of doing it

Comment: How are you deploying the template?

Comment: I am using powershell scripts